# Share Mac internet with iPad using USB

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, internet-sharing

I have read other questions here and can't make this work. I'm trying to Share Mac internet with iPad using USB.
Under settings->network I see which device is connected to internet, for example "wifi". Now under settings->sharing I choose this device under "share your connection from", and then in the "to computers using" I'm choosing "iPad USB". Then I select the checkbox next to "internet sharing" and it says "internet sharing: On". The iPad is connected to the mac. There's no internet in the iPad. Any ideas?

Edit: Sharing the same internet connection over bluetooth works, but I want over USB.

Comment: how are you checking internet in iPad ? did you try safari ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had to trust the device. I tethered the iPad to the mac, went to Finder on the mac, clicked on the iPad menu item in the side bar, then it asked me if I wanted to trust the iPad, I said yes, and then on the iPad it asked for the lock password. After doing this usb internet sharing started to work. I hope this helps someone because this step was not mentioned in any of the other questions or the documentation.